# PHP can't search alias directory XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I have my server set up and I can send images from the htdocs/images folder. However, I want to display images from outside of the htdocs folder.

In my httpd.conf file, I created an alias, so now /myimages links to the appropriate folder on my computer. If I navigate to localhost/myimages, I get the index of myimages and it displays a listing of all my images.

Whenever I directly access the file, say

```
$file = "myimages/image.jpg";
```

It works perfectly fine, I return the image as I expect. The problem comes in when I try to look for the image instead of directly accessing it.

Whenever I try to do:

```
$files = scandir($dir);
```

Where $dir is "images" or "myimages" it just returns an error message saying no such file or directory.

My intention is to set it up so that I can search for the file I wanted by some text input from the user and serve up the file. However, it seems to be a problem that it's an alias and not actually there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the alias will work for the web-server but scandir() is not using the web-server you want to set up a [Symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Comment: I made a symbolic link for myimages that points to where it is in the filesystem, but it still doesn't work and returns the same error.

Comment: the theory is sound, your going to have to provide more information.

Comment: Nevermind, I placed the symbolic link outside of the htdocs folder (silly me). It's working now, thanks.